# How to make the whole anchor clickable, not only the text inside?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the whole anchor clickable, not only the text inside of it?

I've tried to google the question before asking it here, but all the solutions I got weren't fixing the problem for me.

```css
/* Header Buttons Code */

.headerbutton {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.headerbutton:hover {
  background-color: #6abe97;
}


/* Header Settings */

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ed0404;
  margin: -8px;
}


/* Links In Header Code */

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* Background Of Links In Header While Hoover */

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #C0A9BD;
  color: black;
}


/* Active Link In Header*/

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}


/* 3 Buttons Potition Setting In Header */

.header-right {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Logo Position Setting */

.header-left {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}


/*Logo Size Setting */

.logo-container img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}


/*Footer Setting*/

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="./media/Logo.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <div id="Contact" class="headerbutton">
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
      <div id="about" class="headerbutton">
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </div>
      <div id="Cart" class="headerbutton">
        <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: "*but all the solution I got wasn't fixing*" - What have you've actually tried? Please add the attempts to the question as well

Comment: Be careful if you say button as it refers to an actual button, not an anchor that you style as a button. The div that you styled like a button can go inside the anchor or you style the anchor as a button directly.

Comment: The header and multiple anchors are unnecessary. Please use a _minimal_ reproducible example; a single anchor will be enough. P.S. I've edited your question to refer to anchors instead of buttons, as that is what you are actually using.

Answer (score 4):

Add `padding` instead of `margin` on `a` tag.

`Padding` is the space between the content of an element and its border, on the other hand `margin` is the space outside of an element

`Padding` is considered part of the element itself, so its clickable, but
`margins` are not part of the element and do not respond to click events

```css
/* Header Buttons Code */

.headerbutton {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.headerbutton:hover {
  background-color: #6abe97;
}


/* Header Settings */

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ed0404;
  margin: -8px;
}


/* Links In Header Code */

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/* Background Of Links In Header While Hoover */

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #C0A9BD;
  color: black;
}


/* Active Link In Header*/

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}


/* 3 Buttons Potition Setting In Header */

.header-right {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Logo Position Setting */

.header-left {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}


/*Logo Size Setting */

.logo-container img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}


/*Footer Setting*/

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="./media/Logo.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <div id="Contact" class="headerbutton">
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
      <div id="about" class="headerbutton">
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </div>
      <div id="Cart" class="headerbutton">
        <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: There is also another way of doing it, the HTML5 allows `<a>` tag to be wrapped around a `<div>` element. Therefore, the `<div>` will be visible inside the `<anchor>` tag. so you can do:
`<a href="somewhere">
    <div> this now becomes a link </div>
</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use padding instead of margin on the `<a>` element to get the desired size.
Margins don't compute to the actual width of an element. Consider using padding.

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside an `<a>` tag is clickable; so, put your `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag.

```css
/* Header Buttons Code */

.headerbutton {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.headerbutton:hover {
  background-color: #6abe97;
}


/* Header Settings */

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ed0404;
  margin: -8px;
}


/* Links In Header Code */

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* Background Of Links In Header While Hoover */

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #C0A9BD;
  color: black;
}


/* Active Link In Header*/

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}


/* 3 Buttons Potition Setting In Header */

.header-right {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Logo Position Setting */

.header-left {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}


/*Logo Size Setting */

.logo-container img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}


/*Footer Setting*/

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="./media/Logo.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
     
      <a  id="Contact" class="headerbutton" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>

      <a id="about" class="headerbutton" href="about.html">About Us</a>

      <a  id="Cart" class="headerbutton" href="cart.html">Cart</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Maybe I've gone code-blind but, in the snippet you've posted, I don't see a `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag.

Comment: you can add <div> inside <a> tag. Everything you put inside <a> tag will be clickable, you can put <img>, <p>, <h1> etc inside <a> tag.

Comment: Yes, everything inside A tag will be clickable. But in your snippet, there's only `<a id="about" class="headerbutton" href="xxx.html">Xxx Yyy</a>` with no div inside. Your sample code doesn't follow your words, making your answer less useful :(