# How to make the buttons in flex-wrap clickable not only the text inside of the button?

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make the entire button clickable not only the text inside of the button clickable in the flex-wrap property using only HTML and CSS?

I've tried to rewrite the code to work with the results I got from googling or asking AI but all of the solutions ive found didn't work or just fucked the code the design I want to have.

Here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="flex-container wrap">
    <div class="action">
        <a href="action.html">Action Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="animated">
        <a href="animated.html">Animated Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="comedy">
        <a href="comedy.html">Comedy Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Docu">
        <a href="documentary.html">Documentary Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fantasy">
        <a href="fantasy.html">Fantasy Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="horror">
        <a href="horror.html">Horror Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="noir">
        <a href="noir.html">NOIR Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="scifi">
        <a href="scifi.html">Sci-Fi Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="thriller">
        <a href="thriller.html">Thriller Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="truecrime">
        <a href="truecrime.html">True Crime Movies</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code

```
.flex-container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #C0A9BD;
      margin: -10px;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: white;
      width: 90px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 25px;
      font-size: 17px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 15px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .flex-container a:hover {
      background-color: #C0A9BD;
      color: black;
    }

    .wrap { flex-wrap: wrap; }
```

As said above ive tried googling and asking AI but all of the solutions ive got from it was not working and just messing around with the design I tried to get with using the flex-wrap.

Comment: Apply everything you are currently applying to the div, to the link inside of it instead - and add `display: block`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the whole anchor clickable, not only the text inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321689/how-to-make-the-whole-anchor-clickable-not-only-the-text-inside)

Comment: rather than asking your question again, edit your question and provide details and clarity to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the solution:

```
.flex-container :hover {
background-color: #C0A9BD;
color: black;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).